# Small function for getting character value

Tags: c, strings, parsing, xml

I want to extract some values in i-commas(") from lines like this:

```
<P k="9,0,1" vt="191" v="100.99936" z="" />
```

Example:

```
getCharVal ( cp, char "k=\"", 9)
```

where cp is a pointer the line above should return "9,0,1"

The function:

```
#define  ENDTAG   "/>"
#define ICOMMAS   '"'
char * getCharVal ( char *cp, char *att, size_t s)
{
  char * val;
  char * endTagP;
  if (cp == NULL)return NULL;
  cp = strstr(cp, att)+strlen(att);
  if (cp == NULL) return NULL;
  char * endP = strchr(cp, ICOMMAS);
  if (endP == NULL) return NULL;
  endTagP = strstr(cp, ENDTAG);
  if (endTagP == NULL) return NULL;
  if (endP > endTagP) return NULL;
  size_t valsize    = endP - cp ;
  if (valsize > s) return NULL;
  val = malloc(valsize + 1);
  memcpy (val, cp, valsize);
  val[valsize]='\0';
  cp = endTagP;
  return val;

}
```

This code is ugly.  Could anyone give me hints on how to write it better?

Comment: [Use a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)! (seriously, **don't!**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've modified your code to make it more normal C99, including adding `const`
to parameters that your function does not change, improving (to my taste) the
variable names, moving variable definition to the point of their first use and
using `strndup` to duplicate the tag (not universally available but easily
written).

```
char *getCharVal(const char *ch, const char *att, size_t size)
{
    if (!ch) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ch = strstr(ch, att);
    if (!ch) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ch += strlen(att);

    char *end = strchr(ch, '"');
    if (!end) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *endTag = strstr(ch, ENDTAG);
    if (!endTag) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (end > endTag) {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t valSize = end - ch;
    if (valSize > size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return strndup(ch, valSize);
}
```

Note also that your

```
cp = strstr(cp, att)+strlen(att);
if (cp == NULL) return NULL;
```

will never fail because even if `att` is not found you have added its length
to the NULL pointer that `strstr` would return.

A beneficial change would be to omit the check for size (although perhaps your
application is such that this check is more necessary than it appears).

Finally, I think your interface is ugly.  It would be much cleaner to pass the
the pure attribute "k".  However, I can see that passing "k=\"" is an
optimisation that makes the function much simpler to implement.

Comment: Didn't notice: `cp = strstr(cp, att)+strlen(att);`. Goo eye.

Comment: Do you also recommend the change it and use standard xml libraries?

Comment: Size is checked because it is stream and sometimes comes something wrong.

Comment: Depends. If if you only ever want to extract "k" from your stream then using your own function might be sensible.  But if you need to extract more and/or your XML can be badly formed a library is likely to make the job much easier.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest code to maintain is code that doesn't exist.  For parsing XML, use an XML-parsing library, preferably with XPath support.  Sometimes it *might* be justified to whip up your own code to extract values from XML, but it clearly does not make sense in this case.  Not only is the code ugly by your own admission, low-level string- and memory-manipulation also distracts you from thinking about the big picture.  Furthermore, your code will be less robust than a proper XML parser, and it will fail if the text is encoded in a semantically equivalent variant (for example, if a value is escaped).

Comment: Definitely use a tried and true library, but as a exercise or for fun, try to write these yourself. You'll become a better programmer for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

Work on the algorithm first before you think about error checking. You know you'll input information correctly. The basic algorithm follows:

```
char *getCharVal(char *cp, char *att, size_t s)
{
    char *val, *pChStart, *pChEnd;
    size_t valLen;

    pChStart = strstr(cp, att);      // Find value substring in source string
    pChStart += strlen(att);         // Go to beginning of value substring
    pChEnd = strstr(pChStart, "\""); // Find end of value substring
    valLen = pChEnd - pChStart;      // Calculate length of value substring

    val = malloc(valLen * sizeof(char) + 1); // Allocate memory for value substring
    strncpy(val, pChStart, valLen);          // Copy value in source string to value substring copy
    val[valLen] = '\0';                      // NULL terminate value substring copy

    return val;
}
```

Once you get the algorithm down, you can add error checking. You know you'll be checking for `NULL` a lot, so instead of using a lot of `if` statements in the source code, which adds clutter and makes things less readable, add a macro to "hide" it:

```
#define CHECK_NULL(string) (if((string) == NULL) return NULL)
```

With this, you can check for `NULL`s in a less obtrusive way:

```
 CHECK_NULL(pChStart == strstr(cp, att));
```

Your code with the `CHECK_NULL` macro is much more readable:

```
char * getCharVal ( char *cp, char *att, size_t s)
{
    char * val;
    char * endTagP;
    char * endP;

    CHECK_NULL(cp);
    CHECK_NULL(strstr(cp, att)+strlen(att));
    CHECK_NULL(endP = strchr(cp, ICOMMAS));
    CHECK_NULL(strstr(cp, ENDTAG));

    size_t valsize = endP - cp ;
    if (valsize > s) return NULL;

    CHECK_NULL(val = malloc(valsize + 1));
    memcpy (val, cp, valsize);
    val[valsize]='\0';
    cp = endTagP;

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, `malloc` should not be cast, the OP is correct in using `memcpy` instead of your `strncpy` (he knows the length) and that multiple vars are usually best not declared on the same line but are often better defined at the point of first use.  Encouraging the use of macros is also not something I would do and encouraging their use to hide error handling is arguably wrong.

Comment: @WilliamMorris OP tagged this C, so variables at top is convention. Using old compiler... I forgot to take the cast that it requires out. Chars are not always one byte. The macro is simple and it's obvious what it does.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1. By definition. The macro call is only "obvious" here because the definition is right above it. In normal use it will not be, and so without looking up the definition there is no way to know what happens if its "check" turns out false.  And what happens when you have another use case where the return needs to be -1 instead of NULL? Another macro with a similar name?  Use of macros is discouraged for good reasons.

Comment: @WilliamMorris http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684056/is-using-sizeofchar-when-dynamically-allocating-a-char-redundant You are correct sir.  My apologies.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits i really like your solution. I really didn't know to whom  I should give "accepted". I decided for Morris because of his further explanation. Anyhow big thanks and I'll use some of you ideas too.

Comment: @MaMu Morris has more experience than I, so you made a good choice. Keep up the great work!

Comment: @FiddlingBits Your solution seems more elegant to me. But I'm very beginner to c and have much less experience comparing to both of you.